# SQL to insert data read from excel using PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am currently working on reading a excel using php and storing those records in **mysql**.I came across PHPExcel,a bunch of very nice plugin classes which can very easily help to achive it.I tried to search through but did not something similar to my use case.Also,not very good at **object oriented PHP** and I am short of time in doing this.

```
    First Name  Last Name   Nationality Gender  Date of Birth   Time of Birth   Date/Time   PHP Coder   Sanity %Age
```

Above are my sample **database columns** and **First** row of my excel sheet.I want to match the column names of my rows before inserting them to database.
My code till now gives me a 2 dimensional array in which I get the column names and values.The reason I want to check the column name before inserting is that,my excels can be in any order of the column names.
I used exampleReader01 in the package and some SO reference to achieve this.

```
  $headingsArray = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',null, true, true, true);
  $headingsArray = $headingsArray[1];
  $r = -1;
  $namedDataArray = array();
  for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
  $dataRow = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,null, true, true, true);
  if ((isset($dataRow[$row]['A'])) && ($dataRow[$row]['A'] > '')) {
       ++$r;
  foreach($headingsArray as $columnKey => $columnHeading){
      $namedDataArray[$r][$columnHeading] = $dataRow[$row][$columnKey];
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want some help how can I insert this in the right column.
My array is like this

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [First Name] => Mark
        [Last Name] => Baker
        [Nationality] => British
        [Gender] => M
        [Date of Birth] => 19-Dec-60
        [Time of Birth] => 1:30
        [Date/Time] => 22269.0625
        [PHP Coder] => 1
        [Sanity %Age] => 32%
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [First Name] => Toni
        [Last Name] => Baker
        [Nationality] => British
        [Gender] => F
        [Date of Birth] => 24-Nov-50
        [Time of Birth] => 20:00
        [Date/Time] => 18591.83333
        [PHP Coder] => 
        [Sanity %Age] => 95%
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [First Name] => Rachel
        [Last Name] => Baker
        [Nationality] => British
        [Gender] => F
        [Date of Birth] => 7-Dec-82
        [Time of Birth] => 0:15
        [Date/Time] => 30292.01042
        [PHP Coder] => 
        [Sanity %Age] => 100%
    )

 )
```

Hope I am clear.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can assume that your Excel column header names never change, why not simply use a mapping array?

```
$dbMapping = array(
    'col1' => header1,
    'col2' => header2,
     ..
    'colN' => headerN
);
```

So when you're ready to insert to the database, you iterate through each row with the column header names you already have in your 2D array and pass it into your mapping array i.e. $dbMapping['col1'] and that will get you your header name and you can grab the correct row value.

psuedo

```
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
     insert into col1, col2, ... colN
       values ($rows[$dbMapping['col1']], $rows[$dbMapping['col2']], ...
 }
```

Of course it would be in your best interest to use parameterized values.

Comment: If I am getting you right,you mean I should have a static array,that has my column names and my map it with column number in database.
Ex:`First Name=>col1,Last Name=>col2` and so on.Can you please elaborate a bit on the logic how can I check the mapping,I have added my table structure and column names.
Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: Sorry, had to switch the $dbMapping values, but I've updated it a bit with psuedo code to show the general idea

Comment: I tried like this `foreach($namedDataArray as $key=>$value)
{ $sql="insert into tbl_user (".$fieldset.")values("."'".$value['First Name']."'".","."'".$value['Last Name']."'".","."'".$value['Nationality']."'".","."'".$value['Gender']."'".","."'".$value['Date of Birth']."'".","."'".$value['Time of Birth']."'".","."'".$value['Date/Time']."'".","."'".$value['PHP Coder']."'".","."'".$value['Sanity %Age']."'".")";
}` But this is good when the columns order does not change(in excel). $fieldset holds the column list.But my excel may come in different order of columns but the names would be consistent

Comment: I think it should be `values ($row[$dbMapping['col1']], $row[$dbMapping['col2']]` instead of `values ($rows[$dbMapping['col1']], $rows[$dbMapping['col2']]` Pls edit,I tried but failed.Thanks,I will try it and mark it as accepted.Upvoted already. :)

Comment: That is exactly where a $dbMapping array would be useful.  The order of your INSERT statement never changes.  So, if you have $dbMapping[col1] = 'First Name', then $value[$dbMapping[col1]] will always give you the correct value for 'col1'

Comment: Thanks for the help.I would like to know if you can help me over the upload part is well.I want to upload the excel and then read it.So,when the user clicks on upload and selects a file,immediately the file should load.(Not like the traditional click on submit button of the form to upload it and display results)